# how to find differences in the sequence between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables (one old archive and one new archive) with 3 columns, where the first colum is a sort of hierarchy and the other two are values with cant and wont be duplicated. Per hierarchy it needs to check if the sequence of the two colums are exactly the same in both tables. If not, I want it to show the whole Hierarchy where the change is. So for example:

table1:

```
 colum1     colum2    colum3
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder4 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
```

table2:

```
 colum1     colum2    colum3
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder2 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |
--------------------------------
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |
--------------------------------
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |
--------------------------------
```

So if some values are switched or missing between 1 hierarchy it will show the whole hierarchy. From the example from above the result would look like this:

```
             table1                        table2

 colum1     colum2    colum3     colum1    colum2    colum3
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 | folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |  <--- was switched
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 | folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 | folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |  <--- was switched
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 | folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 | folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |  <--- was switched
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 | folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |  <--- was switched
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 | folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder4 | detail2 | detail20 |         |         |          |  <---missing
---------------------------------------------------------------
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 | folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

So is this somehow possible? I want to use SQL for this, but maybe another language is more handy? Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How shall the algorithm/query decide whether a row in table2 was switched or is missing? For example, why isn't the last line of your result marked as missing, whereas the line before is marked as switched?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this. One way is to use the tablediff utility. 
[tablediff utility - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx)
[tablediff utility intro](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-tablediff-utility/)

Comment: @StephanLechner, good question. to be honest, it doenst really matter if the user can see that the row was switched or missing. As long as the whole hierarchy gets shown when there is an difference

Comment: @SqlZim, I just tried this, but my table doenst have an unique ID. So it cant be done with tablediff i guess

Comment: @SqlZim I ment primary key

Comment: Table data has no inherent order. So it makes no difference if you *show* `folder1 | detail1 | detail10` before or after `folder1 | detail3 | detail30`; it has no *position* in the table. Or is there another field in the table indicating some order (a sequence number or a date maybe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we added an id to each table and relied on insert order to mean something (or if there exists some other ordinal or sort to use), you could do this:

updated to check based on folders with row_number():

Example test setup: http://rextester.com/VXZIP45848

```
create table a (
    id int not null identity(1,1)
  , one varchar(32)
  , two varchar(32)
  , three varchar(32))
insert into a values 
 ('folder1','detail1','detail10')
,('folder1','detail2','detail20')
,('folder1','detail3','detail30')
,('folder1','detail 98','detail 198')
,('folder2','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail2','detail20')
,('folder2','detail3','detail30')
,('folder1','detail99','detail 199')
,('folder3','detail1','detail10')
,('folder3','detail2','detail20')
,('folder3','detail3','detail30')
,('folder4','detail1','detail10')
,('folder4','detail2','detail20')
,('folder4','detail3','detail30');


create table b (
    id int not null identity(1,1)
  , one varchar(32)
  , two varchar(32)
  , three varchar(32))
insert into b values 
 ('folder1','detail3','detail30')
,('folder1','detail2','detail20')
,('folder1','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail2','detail20')
,('folder2','detail3','detail30')
,('folder3','detail1','detail10')
,('folder3','detail3','detail30')
,('folder3','detail2','detail20')
,('folder4','detail1','detail10')
,('folder4','detail3','detail30')
,('folder5','detail5','detail50');

/* show all a and all b when matched and when not */

select a.*, b.*, diff=case 
    when a.rn=b.rn    then ''
    when a.id is null then 'not in a'
    when b.id is null then 'not in b'
    when a.rn!=b.rn   then 'switched'
    else '?' 
    end
  from (select * ,rn = row_number() over (partition by one order by id)
          from a) as a
      full outer join 
        (select * ,rn = row_number() over (partition by one order by id)
          from b) as b
            on a.one=b.one
           and a.two=b.two
           and a.three=b.three
```

results in:

```
+------+---------+-----------+------------+------+------+---------+---------+----------+------+----------+
|  id  |   one   |    two    |   three    |  rn  |  id  |   one   |   two   |  three   |  rn  |   diff   |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+------+------+---------+---------+----------+------+----------+
| 1    | folder1 | detail1   | detail10   | 1    | 3    | folder1 | detail1 | detail10 | 3    | switched |
| 2    | folder1 | detail2   | detail20   | 2    | 2    | folder1 | detail2 | detail20 | 2    |          |
| 3    | folder1 | detail3   | detail30   | 3    | 1    | folder1 | detail3 | detail30 | 1    | switched |
| 4    | folder1 | detail 98 | detail 198 | 4    | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | NULL | not in b |
| 8    | folder1 | detail99  | detail 199 | 5    | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | NULL | not in b |
| 5    | folder2 | detail1   | detail10   | 1    | 4    | folder2 | detail1 | detail10 | 1    |          |
| 6    | folder2 | detail2   | detail20   | 2    | 5    | folder2 | detail2 | detail20 | 2    |          |
| 7    | folder2 | detail3   | detail30   | 3    | 6    | folder2 | detail3 | detail30 | 3    |          |
| 9    | folder3 | detail1   | detail10   | 1    | 7    | folder3 | detail1 | detail10 | 1    |          |
| 10   | folder3 | detail2   | detail20   | 2    | 9    | folder3 | detail2 | detail20 | 3    | switched |
| 11   | folder3 | detail3   | detail30   | 3    | 8    | folder3 | detail3 | detail30 | 2    | switched |
| 12   | folder4 | detail1   | detail10   | 1    | 10   | folder4 | detail1 | detail10 | 1    |          |
| 13   | folder4 | detail2   | detail20   | 2    | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | NULL | not in b |
| 14   | folder4 | detail3   | detail30   | 3    | 11   | folder4 | detail3 | detail30 | 2    | switched |
| NULL | NULL    | NULL      | NULL       | NULL | 12   | folder5 | detail5 | detail50 | 1    | not in a |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+------+------+---------+---------+----------+------+----------+
```

---

Since there is no ordinal or sort, finding cases of 'switching' aren't possible in this case.

Example test setup: http://rextester.com/YEIAN6814

```
/* since there is no ordinal or sort, 
  finding cases of 'switching' aren't possible in this case. */

create table a (one varchar(32), two varchar(32), three varchar(32))
insert into a values 
 ('folder1','detail1','detail10')
,('folder1','detail2','detail20')
,('folder1','detail3','detail30')
,('folder2','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail2','detail20')
,('folder2','detail3','detail30')
,('folder3','detail1','detail10')
,('folder3','detail2','detail20')
,('folder3','detail3','detail30')
,('folder4','detail1','detail10')
,('folder4','detail2','detail20')
,('folder4','detail3','detail30');

create table b (one varchar(32), two varchar(32), three varchar(32))
insert into b values 
 ('folder1','detail3','detail30')
,('folder1','detail2','detail20')
,('folder1','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail1','detail10')
,('folder2','detail2','detail20')
,('folder2','detail3','detail30')
,('folder3','detail1','detail10')
,('folder3','detail3','detail30')
,('folder3','detail2','detail20')
,('folder4','detail1','detail10')
,('folder4','detail3','detail30')
,('folder5','detail5','detail50'); /* added this value for example*/
```

---

Full Outer Join: show all `a` and all `b` either when matched or not

```
/* show all a and all b when matched and when not */
select a.*, b.*
  , diff=case 
      when a.one is null then 'not in a'
      when b.one is null then 'not in b'
      else ''
      end
  from a 
    full outer join b on a.one  =b.one
      and isnull(a.two,'')  =isnull(b.two,'')
      and isnull(a.three,'')=isnull(b.three,'')
      --and (a.two  =b.two or (a.two is null and b.two is null))
      --and (a.three=b.three or (a.three is null and b.three is null))

+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   one   |   two   |  three   |   one   |   two   |  three   |   diff   |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 | folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |          |
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 | folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |          |
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 | folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |          |
| folder2 | detail1 | detail10 | folder2 | detail1 | detail10 |          |
| folder2 | detail2 | detail20 | folder2 | detail2 | detail20 |          |
| folder2 | detail3 | detail30 | folder2 | detail3 | detail30 |          |
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 | folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |          |
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 | folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |          |
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 | folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |          |
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 | folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |          |
| folder4 | detail2 | detail20 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | not in b |
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 | folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |          |
| NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | folder5 | detail5 | detail50 | not in a |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

---

Left Join: all `a`, `b` when matched

```
/* show all a, b matches */
select a.*, b.*
from a 
    left join b on a.one  =b.one
      and isnull(a.two,'')  =isnull(b.two,'')
      and isnull(a.three,'')=isnull(b.three,'')
      --and (a.two  =b.two or (a.two is null and b.two is null))
      --and (a.three=b.three or (a.three is null and b.three is null))

+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
|   one   |   two   |  three   |   one   |   two   |  three   |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 | folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 | folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 | folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder2 | detail1 | detail10 | folder2 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder2 | detail2 | detail20 | folder2 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder2 | detail3 | detail30 | folder2 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 | folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 | folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 | folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 | folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder4 | detail2 | detail20 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 | folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
```

---

Not Exists(): all rows from `a` that aren't in `b`

```
/* all in a that aren't in b */
select src='a not in b', * 
  from a 
  where not exists (
      select 1 
        from b 
        where a.one=b.one 
          and isnull(a.two,'')  =isnull(b.two,'')
          and isnull(a.three,'')=isnull(b.three,'')
      );

+------------+---------+---------+----------+
|    src     |   one   |   two   |  three   |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+
| a not in b | folder4 | detail2 | detail20 |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

---

Not Exists(): all rows from `b` that aren't in `a`

```
/* all in b that aren't in a */
select src='b not in a', * 
  from b 
  where not exists (
      select 1 
        from a
        where a.one=b.one 
          and isnull(a.two,'')  =isnull(b.two,'')
          and isnull(a.three,'')=isnull(b.three,'')
      );

+------------+---------+---------+----------+
|    src     |   one   |   two   |  three   |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+
| b not in a | folder5 | detail5 | detail50 |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

---

Except: distinct values in `a` that aren't in `b`

```
/* distinct values in a that aren't in b */
select * from a
except 
select * from b;


+---------+---------+----------+
|   one   |   two   |  three   |
+---------+---------+----------+
| folder4 | detail2 | detail20 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

---

Intersect: distinct values that are in `a` that are also in `b`

```
/* distinct values that are in a that are also in b */
select * from a
intersect 
select * from b;


+---------+---------+----------+
|   one   |   two   |  three   |
+---------+---------+----------+
| folder1 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder1 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder1 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder2 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder2 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder2 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder3 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder3 | detail2 | detail20 |
| folder3 | detail3 | detail30 |
| folder4 | detail1 | detail10 |
| folder4 | detail3 | detail30 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Het @ SqlZim, the first result looks exactly what I want and thanks for putting so much effort in helping me. Tho I prefer to see the old values of my old table, so I can see the errors myself and also can see them in the `diff` column. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you switch the `full outer join` to `left join` like the third example, the results won't include values that are in `b` that aren't in `a`, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Okay thanks, tho it seems to fail with my specific tables... :/

Comment: okay I got an error when for example there are two identical rows like this: `folder6 | null | null`, tho those are both identical, it doenst notice that those are identical

Comment: Also when there are two `not in a` or `not in b` are behind each other, the rest of the table compare fails. Sorry to bother you so much btw

Comment: I fixed that there are no `null` values in my table, but still when there are two values which are not in table `a` or table `b` behind each other, the comparing will not work

Comment: I updated my answer to handle nulls in columns two and three. I'm not sure what you mean by "behind each other".

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. I mean if you for example add 2 random values in a table which the other table doenst have like those: `folder1 | detail 98 | detail 198` and `folder1 | detail99 | detail 199` try to add those in one of the tables bevind the last value of folder1 and before the first value of folder 2

Comment: I think you need to do something with `id = id + 1 ` when a specific row is only in one table

Comment: Updated the answer to use `row_number()` over the folders. This will still return 'switched' when a detail is missing because it changes the order. e.g. folder4, detail3, detail30 is marked as 'switched'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132842/discussion-between-sqlzim-and-wouter-de-jong).